# Novice transformation using apply-templates and string manipulation in the child node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file and I want to convert into a xml file.

Input XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<CONTACTS>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Arun_niit</FirstName>
        <LastName>Arun_niit</LastName>
        <EMail>nura_ice@yahoo.co.in</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>FodenBen'</FirstName>
        <LastName>Ben' Foden</LastName>
        <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002440474277</URL>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>GhorbelMahmoud</FirstName>
        <LastName>Mahmoud Ghorbel</LastName>
        <EMail>mahmoud.ghorbel@alcatel-lucent.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>keyankarthik</FirstName>
        <LastName>karthik keyan</LastName>
        <EMail>karthycse@yahoo.co.in</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Rangarajkarthik</FirstName>
        <LastName>karthik Rangaraj</LastName>
        <EMail>kart2006@gmail.com</EMail>
        <EMail>karthikrangaraj@yahoo.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>ReddyAkky</FirstName>
        <LastName>Akky Reddy</LastName>
        <EMail>akkireddych@gmail.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>SandfordFrankie</FirstName>
        <LastName>Frankie Sandford</LastName>
        <URL>http://www.facebook.com/FrankieSandfordApprovedPage</URL>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>TheSatsRochelle</FirstName>
        <LastName>Rochelle TheSats</LastName>
        <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002487211054</URL>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>KumarVeera</FirstName>
        <LastName>Veera_Kumar</LastName>
        <EMail>KUMARg_81@yahoo.com</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

I want the output like this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTACTS>
<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65539</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>Arun_niit</FirstName>
<LastName>Arun_niit</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<Emails>
<Email Type="yahoo" Value="nura_ice@yahoo.co.in"/>
</Emails>
</CONTACT>

<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65546</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>FodenBen'</FirstName>
<LastName>Ben' Foden</LastName>
<URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100002440474277</URL>
<Facebook-ID>100002440474277</Facebook-ID>
<EMAILS/>
</CONTACT>

<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65553</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>GhorbelMahmoud</FirstName>
<LastName>Mahmoud Ghorbel</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<Emails>
<Email Type="alcatel-lucent" Value="mahmoud.ghorbel@alcatel-lucent.com"/>
</Emails>

<CONTACT>
<PDE-Identity>N65567</PDE-Identity>
<FirstName>Rangarajkarthik</FirstName>
<LastName>karthik Rangaraj</LastName>
<Facebook-ID/>
<Emails>
<Email Type="gmail" Value="kart2006@gmail.com"/>
<Email Type="yahoo" Value="karthikrangaraj@yahoo.com"/>
</Emails>
</CONTACT>

</CONTACTS>
```

Any idea guys, I have learnt about xslt and i tried to add like this:

This is my xslt file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
        <xsl:copy>
               <PDE-Identity>
               <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/> 
               </PDE-Identity>
              <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName|LastName|URL"/>
              <Facebook-ID><!-- To extract the ID value from URL/Email -->
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="URL">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(URL,'?id=')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                   <!-- <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(EMail[1],'@')"/>-->
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Facebook-ID>
            <EMAILS>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="EMail"/>
            </EMAILS>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EMail">
        <EMail Type="<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'@'), '.')"/>" Value="<xsl:value-of select="."/>"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It didn't work. Please help me out guys. Example code; thanks guys.

Comment: Please consider of improving your question, adding more details and asking for a meaningful output.

Comment: Your examples don't make sense. In the expected output you use different contact names?

Comment: Sorry guys; that was a big mistake. Thanks for your support guys.

Comment: Your XML is mismatched. It's not valid XML.

Comment: -1 for initially confusing question, +1 for taking care of it afterward. See my answer, hope having `type` not capitalized is not a problem. In XSLT 1.0 it can be fixed with `translate` anyway. Cheers

Comment: I've changed the title to match better the contents of this question. Feel free to revert back to the original if you care about it.

Comment: @karthik seems you have changed your question. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I have problem with parsing the xml file so i would like to change the xml format. But I'm trying with that but it's not working.I couldn't post another question cause in this website because of my poor knowledge in writing and also in programming. So i have  edited my old question. I'm sorry. I hope you could help me with this ... Thank you Empo for taking following this question.

Comment: Hi i fixed it.     <xsl:template match="EMail">
        <!-- To extract the Emails based on domain value from EMAIL -->
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="Type">
            <xsl:value-of select ="substring-before(substring-after(.,'@'), '.')" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="Value">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> Thank you very much. If you can please change revert back to the old question. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName|LastName"/>
            <EMAILS>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="EMail"/>
            </EMAILS>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EMail">
        <EMail>
            <type><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                    substring-after(.,'@'),
                    '.')"/>
            </type>
            <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
        </EMail>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given your input, produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CONTACTS>
   <CONTACT>
      <FirstName>AfgZohal</FirstName>
      <LastName>Zohal Afg</LastName>
      <EMAILS/>
   </CONTACT>
   <CONTACT>
      <FirstName>Rangarajkarthik</FirstName>
      <LastName>karthik Rangaraj</LastName>
      <EMAILS>
         <EMail>
            <type>gmail</type>
            <value>kart2006@gmail.com</value>
         </EMail>
         <EMail>
            <type>yahoo</type>
            <value>karthikrangaraj@yahoo.com</value>
         </EMail>
      </EMAILS>
   </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

Comment: Thank u so much Empo. Could you please put some nice tutorial links for how to make a html table from XML file. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi empo, I'm trying to add an ID and select the value from http:// in url(http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000689849077). I'm trying in this way,  <ID>
         <xsl:value-of select="CONTACT/URL[type/='@id']"/>
         </ID>; it's not displaying the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="/contacts">
    <contacts>
        <xsl:apply-templates match="contact" />
    </contacts>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/contacts">
    <contact>
        <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="LastName" />
        <xsl:if test="email">
            <emails>
                <xsl:apply-templates match="email" />
            </emails>
        </xsl:if>
    </contact>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="email">
    <email>
        <type>...</type>
        <value><xsl:value-of select="." /></value>
    </email>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Eric, I'm getting output like this:        <FirstName>Rangarajkarthik</FirstName>
        <LastName>karthik Rangaraj</LastName>
        <EMail><type>...</type><value>kart2006@gmail.com</value></EMail>
        <EMail><type>...</type><value>karthikrangaraj@yahoo.com</value></EMail>