# How to check element existence and select substring of element value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, addition

I have an XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250"?>
<CONTACTS>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>AfgZohal</FirstName>
        <LastName>Zohal Afg</LastName>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Arun_niit</FirstName>
        <LastName>Arun_niit</LastName>
        <EMail>nura_ice@yahoo.co.in</EMail>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
        <FirstName>Bá»‘ng M&#xc5;©nHá&#xba;&#xa3;i</FirstName>
        <LastName>Há&#xba;&#xa3;i Anh Bá»‘ng M&#xc5;©n</LastName>
        <URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000689849077</URL>
    </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

I want to add an element ID before FirstName in my xml file;I would like to extract ID from URL tag if URL is available or I want to extract the first six letters from Email address to put it in the ID(unique). Because in some contacts, there is no URL. I using XSLT for this.
In my XSl file i tried in this way

```
   <ID>
     <xsl:value-of select="CONTACT/URL[//http='@id']"/>
     </ID>
```

but it's not working, this is my XSL file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
        <xsl:copy>
         <ID>
         <xsl:value-of select="CONTACT/URL[//http='@id']"/>
         </ID>
              <xsl:copy-of select="FirstName|LastName|URL"/>
            <EMAILS>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="EMail"/>
            </EMAILS>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="EMail">
        <EMail>
            <Type><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(
                    substring-after(.,'@'),
                    '.')"/>
            </Type>
            <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
        </EMail>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is my output xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONTACTS>
<CONTACT>
<ID/>
<FirstName>AfgZohal</FirstName>
<LastName>Zohal Afg</LastName>
<EMAILS/>
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
<ID/>
<FirstName>Arun_niit</FirstName>
<LastName>Arun_niit</LastName>
<EMAILS>
<EMail>
<Type>yahoo</Type>
<Value>nura_ice@yahoo.co.in</Value>
</EMail>
</EMAILS>
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
<ID/>
<FirstName>Bá»‘ng MÅ©nHáº£i</FirstName>
<LastName>Háº£i Anh Bá»‘ng MÅ©n</LastName>
<URL>http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100000689849077</URL>
<EMAILS/>
</CONTACT>
<CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

This is part of my yesterday problem [Novice transformation using apply-templates and string manipulation in the child node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394489/xslt-conversion-xml); since it's a different issue i'm raising a different question.

Comment: When applying formatting to XML code please click the curly bracket button in the GUI editor after having selected the code to format.

Comment: I've changed the title to match the question. Be free to revert to the original if you care about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to select the 'id' part of the url string inside the `URL` element. You should select the substring after `?id=`:

```
 <ID>
 <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(URL,'?id=')"/>
 </ID>
```

Moreover, in the template you are in the context of `CONTACT`, ergo to select a child of it you need just to specify the name of the element. Example:

```
 <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
         <xsl:value-of select="URL"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Will return the value of `URL` while:

```
 <xsl:template match="CONTACT">
         <xsl:value-of select="CONTACT/URL"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

won't return anything, not having `CONTACT` any child of type `CONTACT/URL`.

---

Bonus answer to comment question:

> *I would like to extract ID from URL tag if URL is available or I want to extract the first six letters from Email address to put it in the ID(unique) (...) If we have one/multiple email address then we can select any one of the first six letters from the email address. I thing the contacts must have at least one email address if there is no URL...*

```
        <ID>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="URL">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(URL,'?id=')"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(EMail[1],'@')"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </ID>
```

Comment: Yeap, thanks. If there is no URL value, is it possible to select the first six letters of the email-id from Email for the ID tag. Thank U.

Comment: What do you mean with 'email-id'? Please expand your question by editing it if necessary.

Comment: I would like to extract ID from URL tag if URL is available or I want to extract the first six letters from Email address to put it in the ID(unique). Because in some contacts, there is no URL. I hope this time my question is Ok. Thank u.

Comment: You can have various emails for the same contact or not have email at all. Which email you want? Moreover, why just the first six letters of an email address?

Comment: In XSLT you manage conditions using `xsl:if` or matching templates. Try it  yourself or consider of asking something more precise.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't think about this, thank u. If we have one/multiple email address then we can select any one of the first six letters from the email address. I thing the contacts must have at least one email address if there is no URL... Well i'm trying something like this: <ID><!-- To extract the ID value from URL --> <xsl:choose> <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(URL,'?id=')"/> <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(EMAILS/Value,'@')"/></xsl:otherwise> </xsl:choose> </ID> Thank u.